# Iteration over one derived type only of std::map with base pointers

Tags: c++, collections, polymorphism, std

I have an `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<base>>` m_items in a controller class.

The controller gives items to outside consumers and they only need base so polymorphism works great for that.  However, internally the controller needs to update or delete items of specific types when certain events occur.  The updates are very different in nature and require different sets of data for each event so I can't just have a generic "update" method in the base class.  What I need is a way to iterate only over certain derived types (which I then need to cast to the derived type pointer) when events occur.  One solution is to add a `EDerivedType GetType()` in the base and each derived type returns a different enumeration value so when I iterate I can compare against the required type.  While this works it is not an OO approach.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern can work for you.
Your base class will have an abstract `accept` that gets the visitor as an argument.

Every object will have an `accept` which will call the correct visitor function to do the update.

Comment: Won't work since the operations are very different.  Each type is significantly different in regards to the controller.  The only mutual thing to all of the derived types is that they can be drawn, but each is a logical part of my application representing a different set of data.

Comment: @sprite - in the visitor's `visit` function you get the object itself and write object specific code. I don't see how the fact that the concrete objects are very different from each other make any difference.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood you before. So if I get your intention correctly, the Visitor would be a class representing the event and related data.  I would need a Visit(Derived&) for each derived type in a VisitorBase class with a default implementation that does nothing.  I would then inherit from that class for each operation where I overload only the Visit for the required derived type to perform the needed operation. Is this correct?

Comment: @sprite - Yes. just one thing - you can either use a different derived visitor for each `Derived` or put the logic of all (or some) in one class - especially if they can reuse some code (according to what you said there will be no sheared code). The second advantage of using one class is that you will run over your list just once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have catched the idea: " What I need is a way to iterate only over certain derived types (which I then need to cast to the derived type pointer) when events occur. "

you may keep a `std::map< EDerivedType, Controlloer *>` and find the corresponding Controller directly. In addition, Controller should be a polymorphism base class.

Comment: I can't have many controllers for this.  I need one controller for all the logic.  So having a myriad of controller classes is out of the question.  If I use a map for each type it may work, but I'll end up with some 20 maps and that would be a messy code.  What I want it iteration over a derived type only out of all the objects in one collection held as pointers to base.